# Auto transfer files in FTP with FileZilla

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I want to auto transfer my files to my server after saving them, like in Dreamweaver and Notepad++. As of today i need to confirm the process before FileZilla transfers the files. Is there a solution or workaround for this problem?

Comment: Off-topic here, see [FAQ].

Answer (score 3):

Looks like filezilla does not provide a solution, but other programs mentioned in this form:

- http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5416
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803482/how-to-autoftp-with-filezilla

This person got auto upload to work with a specific editor:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358526/auto-upload-to-filezilla-from-textmate